# How to print data split into train- and test-data sets in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

I have a data set loaded by pandas. My data set looks like:

| hour | score |
| --- | --- |
| 0.5 | 10.0 |
| 1.2 | 8.0 |
| 1.8 | 14.0 |
| 2.4 | 26.0 |
| 2.6 | 22.0 |
| 3.2 | 30.0 |

I wrote the code shown below:

```py
data = pd.read_csv("file_name")
X = data["hour"][:] ; Y = data["score"][:]
train_ratio = 0.8 ; test_ratio = 0.2
Ndata = len(X)
NumTrainData = int(Ndata*train_ratio)
NumTestData = int(Ndata*test_ratio)

train_set, test_set = torch.utils.data.random_split(data, [NumTrainData, NumTestData])
```

I want to check which data are stored in `train_set` and which in `test_set`. How can I check them?

Answer (score 0):

`torch.utils.data.random_split` returns `torch.utils.data.Dataset` object ([official doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html)).

These object are iterators and can be browsed simply with a for loop:

```py
def show_dataset(dataset: torch.utils.data.Dataset, num_elem: int = 5):
    for i, sample in enumerate(dataset):
        print(sample)
        if i == num_elem:
            break
```

Now you can display your top elements:

```py
print('train dataset:')
show_dataset(train_set)
print('test dataset:')
show_dataset(test_set)
```